# LazyColumn loads infinitely when UUID is used to generate key

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a LazyColumn and need a unique key for every item(in my case, post). Since my app has a small number of posts there is a big chance that a post will reoccur multiple times in the user's feed. Thus,  using a posts' OID(I use MongoDB) the key is not sustainable. When I try to generate a UUID, the lazy column doesn't load anymore. What should I do? P.S. I also tried using the posts' OID and it works, but, as expected, when the post reoccurs, the app crashes.

This is the code if it helps:

```
LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        state = lazyColState,
        content = {
            items(items = viewModel.postsList.value,
             key = { UUID.randomUUID().toString() }) { postString ->
                val postDocument = Document.parse(postString)
                PostComposable(
                    owner = postDocument["owner"]!! as String,
                    ownerOID = (postDocument["ownerOID"]!! as ObjectId).toString(),
                    title = postDocument["title"]!! as String,
                    datePosted = postDocument["postingDate"]!! as String,
                    resource = postDocument["resource"]!! as String,
                    numberLikes = postDocument["likes"]!! as Int,
                    postOID = (postDocument["_id"]!! as ObjectId).toString(),
                    navController = navController,
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
                    isOwnedByUser = false,
                    isOnHomePage = true,
                    isSavedDefault = false
                )
            }
    })
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `key` is **optional** for items of `LazyList`, you don't have to use any. It is used to maintain scroll position and optimize recompositions. Generating UUID inside of the `key` lambda doesn't make any sense. If you want to use UUID for key, create the UUID in your ViewModel - when you get the items from db, map them to `Pair<UUID, Post>` or some data class.

Even better, create a key that will look like `"${oid}_${index}"` where index is index of that same item in the list, so you will get something like:

```
"id000_0",
"id001_0",
"id002_0",
"id001_1", ...
```

that way, the first occurrence of an item in the list will always have the same `key`, so you still get reasonable scroll position maintenance and recompositions benefits.